# Ultra96 or Pynq-Z2 kit?

Tags: python, arm, iot, robotics

Which one is more suitable for my project? I want to build a human gesture mimicking Robotic arm. The application is to be built using an open source PYNQ framework. It requires me to choose either one of the kits Ultra96 or PYNQ-Z2 kit for my project so that they can provide me with it. I am unable to find the exact difference between the functionalities of the two, and when to use which? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the Z2 board and it would seem to work just fine for your project. Although I can't speak for the ultra96 it's worth noting that it is a community board and so is not officially supported by Pynq.